# Meteor HTTP.post not working with Trello API

Tags: meteor, trello

I'm trying to create a webhook through the Trello API by using Meteor's HTTP.post method like this:

```
HTTP.post('https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks?key=...&token=...', {
    params: {
        idModel: '...',
        callbackURL: '...'
    },
}, function(error, result) {...});
```

The request works but the response i get is "Invalid value for idModel". However, if i try the same request using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks?key=...&token=...,
    data: {
        idModel: '...',
        callbackURL: '...'
    },
});
```

Everything works fine (i.e. the webhook is created and data is returned). Somehow Meteor's method seems to make it impossible for Trello to parse the idModel field. Any ideas what might be behind this? Am i doing something wrong or is there a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It was sent as `text/plain` before.

```
HTTP.post('https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks?key=...&token=...', {
  params: {
    idModel: '...',
    callbackURL: '...'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}, function(error, result) {...});
```

Comment: Hey @fredick, How did you fixed the webhook,
How can I make a webhook only on a single board,
I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data` instead of `params`:

```
HTTP.post('https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks?key=...&token=...', {
  data: {
    idModel: '...',
    callbackURL: '...'
  },
}, function(error, result) {...});
```

Comment: When i try data instead of params i get the following error in the console:
`OPTIONS https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks?key=...&token=... Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

HTTP.post sent this header:
`Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type`

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing this page because I had the same problem doing this in golang. I solve it by adding

```
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

It is confusing that the 400 message is about an invalid idModel.