# Issue with Trello webhook

Tags: trello

I'm currently working with Trello's API and I'm trying to set a webhook, but I'm running into issues that hopefully someone can help me resolve. First of all in the Trello API and docs (https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/webhooks.html), creating a webhook requires sending the `idModel` as part of the JSON. I guess my first problem is that I'm not sure exactly sure what the `idModel`, or how I can find this id. I tried to use the id I get if I get tokens, but currently I'm getting a 400 response error when I send a request to the following endpoint:

https://trello.com/1/tokens/daf73f1c77efc8f6062aaa94005ab07215d8d390ff2caffe57659707fee32597/webhooks

and my JSON looks something like (replace `callbackURL` with my actual callback URL):

```
{
 description: "My first webhook",
 callbackURL: callbackURL,
 idModel: "54fdef9430a36282010f6230",
}
```

Comment: What type of request are you making?  That should be a PUT or a POST.  Also, you should include the error message that you're getting along with the 400.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your first question, the idModel is the object that you want to monitor. This can be a card, list, board etc.

Get the ids for the lists on a board using the following end point: 
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/[boardID]/lists?key=[App-key]&token=[App-token]

Then use one these ids to monitor a list for changes.

I think the reason you might be getting a 400 error is that you are not passing a key to the web hook creation endpoint.

You have to send a POST request to the endpoint like this:

```
curl \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"description": "My First Webhook",
"callbackURL": "http://www.mywebsite.com/trelloCallback",
"idModel": "4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c"}'
 https://trello.com/1/tokens/[USER_TOKEN]/webhooks/?key=[APPLICATION_KEY]
```

Note that when you make this POST request to create the webhook, Trello will make a HEAD request to your server, and they will expect your server to respond with a 200 status.

Answer (score 0):

plingamp is right. but notice you have an extra , in your JSON body.

it should look like

```
{
 description: "My first webhook",
 callbackURL: callbackURL,
 idModel: "54fdef9430a36282010f6230"
}
```

I suggest you use Postman for this one.
Use a POST request with a raw JSON body, and with the same parameters as you did before.
it should work if the user token and app key are correct (just copy the body I wrote here ), I had the same issue exactly and it worked out.

Also, use  [request bin](http://requestb.in/) and copy the link as the callBackUrl and you will be able to see the POST request made by trello.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22391082/4006407) where the solution was to add a `Content-Type` header to the request. Adding the header `"Content-Type": "applicaton/json"` worked for me.